# MultiLanguage NotesView Content in Xpages

Tags: xpages

I have realized a full Xpages application width > 200 Notes View..and for translate I use the native option "Localization options" into Xpages settings.

All work very well (can now write the translation into -proprierties)

But...

In some Notes View I have the content of some column with embedded @Formulas string in the original language or the date of my field in the format of Domino enviroment (ex. there are @text(datfield;"S0") that return italian format gg\mm\aaaa)

Can I mix the native Multilanguage Database Notes Option with Locazations Options feature?

With native Notes Multilanguage database, is need duplicate the view setting the correct language... but Xpages support this feature when render the object Notes View?

p.s. For native Notes multi-language read this [Redbook](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/domino/OpenAttachment/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/697309BC255A87B585257983005B0D92/attach/IBM%20Lotus%20Domino%20Development%20Best%20Practices%28011212%29.pdf) from page 65

Comment: good question, will be interested to see the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have found that the only solution is a routine JS client insert into
*AfterPageLoad* event with **view.postScript**(Function JS client) 
and *AfterRestoreView* event with the same call **view.postScript**
 convert on.fly the content of my view.
I select the content DOM of my Notes view with dojo.query
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would try to eliminate all the @Text(datefield) entries from the views that you are working with. This will allow the both the notes clients and the ViewPanes in your Xpage applications to automatically display the date in the correct format for the viewer of the application.

Unfortunately, from my testing, it appears that you cannot mix the native multilingual database options with the XPages localization options.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the content of the Notes view because this project is a big work of conversion from Notes Database CRM to Xpages without change the backend...
I think to translate on the fly with dojo.query and manipulate the DOM....I don't have any other idea

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix up those two options, because Notes-based multilingual database option is a part of Notes Client architecture.

If I were you, I create seperate views for XPages application. It's really waste of resources in the mean time (migration phase) but it's the most optimized way I guess. Instead of conforming old-style views, you may redesign your views according to what you need.

For example, in XPages, you don't need many columns to be calculated within the index.

There is no great answer for that :(